# Restore a PostgreSQL dump with backslash quotes to a modern PostgreSQL (9.3)

Tags: sql, postgresql, mediawiki

**Here is the story:**

I have to move mediawiki database from mysql to postgresql on another server and i've found i can just export everything to xml using special script inside mediawiki called "dumpBackup.php". So i did. It've made .xml file with content.

I've moved this file into my new server with postgresql installed. I have also installed new version of mediawiki because my dumpfile doesn't have structure of database.

In next step i've converted this .xml structure to sql dump in postgresql notation by using mwdumper. It created nice file but there is formatting unsupported by my postgresql

Look please, what it have generated:

```
-- MediaWiki XML dump converted to SQL by mwdumper
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE revision DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;ALTER TABLE page DISABLE TRIGGER ALL;;

INSERT INTO pagecontent (old_id,old_text,old_flags) VALUES (1,'\'\'\'Instalacja MediaWiki powiodła się.\'\'\'\n\nZobacz [//meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Contents przewodnik użytkownika] w celu uzyskania informacji o działaniu oprogramowania wiki.\n\n== Na początek ==\n* [//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings Lista ustawień konfiguracyjnych]\n* [//www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ MediaWiki FAQ]\n* [https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-announce Komunikaty o nowych wersjach MediaWiki]','utf-8');
INSERT INTO revision (rev_id,rev_page,rev_text_id,rev_comment,rev_user,rev_user_text,rev_timestamp,rev_minor_edit,rev_deleted) VALUES (1,1,1,'',0,'MediaWiki default','2013-08-10 15:31:56',0,0);

...
```

It isn't full compatible with my postgresql instance.

**Problems:**

- backslash escaping

to solve this i've tried to add
`SET standard_conforming_strings = 'off';` and `SET backslash_quote = 'on';` at the beginning of the file

- it is trying to add content into *public* schema, but i want to add it to *x* schema

to solve this i've tried to add `SET search_path TO x;`

**there is still problem with \'**

Comment: *"There is still problem with `\'`"* . There is? The `SET` commands you added should take care of that. What's the error message? It seems to me like the easiest path here is probably to fix the `mwdumper` code. While you're at it you could submit a patch to the MediaWiki folks so they generate correct dumps in future.

Comment: Why are you using dumpBackup instead of direct DB migration?

Comment: @MaxSem I thought at first dumpBackup is making dump of entire database with users etc. but it doesn't. I've abandoned migrating from mysql to postgresql because I don't have enough time to solve it.

Comment: Yeah, SQL dumps aren't directly compatible between MySQL and PG. Also why are you migrating from MySQL in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally to `standard_conforming_strings = 'off'; backslash_quote = 'on'` in dump file i had also to change strings format from `'...'` to `E'...'`. Notepad++ have buggy replace function so i've used sed.